# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Series' → This is an error running Keras. Pandas is installed, file name is Attempt3.py

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I am trying to build a basic CNN to detect cracks and leaning on the Keras website.

The portion of code with issues is:

---

```
#The base model contains batchnorm layers. We want to keep them in inference mode
#when we unfreeze the base model for fine-tuning, so we make sure that the
#base_model is running in inference mode here.
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)  # Regularize with dropout
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary()

#train the top layer
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
)

model.fit(train_ds, epochs=20, validation_data=val_ds)
```

---

With this I am getting a return of:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\First Surname\Documents\uni\USQ\2021\Coding\Attempt3.py", line 128, in <module>
    model.fit(train_ds, epochs=20, validation_data=val_ds)

  File "C:\Users\First Surname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1133, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(

  File "C:\Users\First Surname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1364, in get_data_handler
    return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\First Surname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1152, in __init__
    adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)

  File "C:\Users\First Surname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 988, in select_data_adapter
    adapter_cls = [cls for cls in ALL_ADAPTER_CLS if cls.can_handle(x, y)]

  File "C:\Users\First Surname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 988, in <listcomp>
    adapter_cls = [cls for cls in ALL_ADAPTER_CLS if cls.can_handle(x, y)]

  File "C:\Users\First Surname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 227, in can_handle
    tensor_types = _get_tensor_types()

  File "C:\Users\First Surname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1637, in _get_tensor_types
    return (ops.Tensor, np.ndarray, pd.Series, pd.DataFrame)

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Series'
```

---

In a minor attempt to fix it with names being confused, the sample on Keras has two `epoch=` to set a variable so I have just removed the `epoch=(number)` variable and placed the number in the `fit(epoch=(number))`.

I am currently uninstalling and reinstalling pandas. and will restart the computer for a 2nd time hoping this will work.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am really struggling

Comment: I suspect that your `train_ds` or `val_ds` are not the correct types, probably the `val_ds`, which needs to be a tuple of np arrays or a tensorflow dataset, or a python generator.

Comment: What is the output of `train_ds.head()`

Comment: Hi all, I found a solution. The Anaconda Navigator wasn't properly installing things. Got it up and running by installing Tensorboard package using the powershell as an administrator and restarting my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The Anaconda Navigator wasn't properly installing things. Got it up and running by installing Tensorboard package using the powershell as an administrator and restarting my computer.